# Cant see objects in render view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

When I switch into Viewport Shading (Cycles) I can't see any objects.
[image]

Comment: May be all of them have transparent material.

Comment: are you willing to post your file?

Comment: All my objects have color on them, it is when i switch view that they all go clear.

Comment: are your light visible in render? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: your computer is taking to calculate sample as you could see on the top left. All you can do is wait